# SPEND [a period of time] ENGAGED/ENGAGING in something

Tags: word-choice, complements, adjuncts

I came across the following sentence in the book - ORIGIN - written by Dan Brown

> Since 1893, hundreds of spiritual leaders from nearly thirty world religions had gathered in a different location every few years to spend a week ***engaged*** in interfaith dialogue.

Is the use of ***engaged*** there correct? Or should it be replaced by ***engaging***?

Comment: Either is possible.

Comment: @ColinFine Which is more common in such sentences?

Comment: I'd tend to favour 'engaged' as the whole sentence is given a past tense ('since 1893', 'had gathered').  But I can see a very good argument for using 'engaging' as well.  Consider, if you were one of the 'spiritual leaders' and asked what you (as a group) had done during the gathering you could answer either way.  'We engaged in interfaith dialogue.' or with the addition of 'were' :'We were engaging in interfaith dialogue.  The first sentence is less wordy and sounds slightly less awkward to me.

Comment: @Man_From_India  I would instead say that "more common" doesn't matter.  Both work, so it's more which *sounds* better for the context, and the individual style of writing.

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference between *"They were engaged"* in something and *"They were engaging"* in something. The first suggests a condition while the second suggests an action. In the context of your question, the meaning is much the same, but in a different context you would use these differently.

> The talks have been going on for hours, so please don't interrupt them while they are **engaged** (deeply involved) in these delicate negotiations.
>
> It's still at a preliminary stage, but the fact the two sides are **engaging** (starting to be involved) in negotiations is encouraging.

Again, it's a subtle difference that in many cases is moot with a verb like "engage".  With other verbs like "to park" there is a big difference in meaning:

> They spent an hour **parked** by the side of the road.
>
> They spent an hour **parking** by the side of the road.

*To be parked* means to have the car fully stopped, while *to be parking* means you're trying to find a place (or a way) to park. So with the first, you're saying that they were stopped in the car for an hour, and the second, that they were looking for parking for an hour.

Please note that the second is not an idiomatic use of "parking".  A native speaker would more likely say:

> They spent an hour **trying to park** by the side of the road.

Unfortunately it also seems difficult to extrapolate this to any general case. It varies from verb to verb. For example:

> They spent a week **stranded** in the mountains

but not *stranding*.

> They spent a week **skiing** in the mountains

but not *skied*.

In other cases a phrasal verb is required for one form, but not the other:

> He spent a week **thinking** how to solve the problem.
>
> He spend a week **in thought** over how to solve the problem.

Maybe over at ELU they can explain the pattern, because I can't see any.

Comment: Andrew, that is obvious, I think. It depends on the verb that is taking *-ing* or *-ed*. Moreover, I think your sentence - *They spent a hour parked by the side of the road* - seems not very correct, if at all, it is marginally correct.

Comment: @Man_From_India  *"They spent an hour parked by/at the side of the road"* is perfectly fine.   What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @Man_From_India  Another example is *convinced/convincing*.  *They spent an hour **convinced** they were going to jail.*  vs.  *They spent an hour **convincing** the judge to let them go.*   If this structure depends entirely on individual verbs, and the only way to learn is memorization, then your extensive answer above has very limited utility.

Comment: Andrew, syntatically there is no problem. But semantically, it seems to me like this *they are parked for an hour by the side of the road*.

Comment: @Man_From_India  It's fine to say, *They **parked** (or **had parked**) for an hour by the side of the road,*  as a past-tense action, or, *They **were parked** for an hour by the side of the road* as a past-tense condition.   One is the verb, the other is the past participle.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the following sentence in Robert Langdon’s *Origin*:

> Since 1893, hundreds of spiritual leaders from nearly thirty world religions had gathered in a different location every few years to spend a week ***engaged*** in interfaith dialogue.

My first reaction was that *there must have been some editing error and that **”engaged”** should be replaced by **”engaging”**.*

Then followed lots of reading, research and talking. And finally I came to this conclusion:

> BOTH “ENGAGED” and “ENGAGING” ARE CORRECT.

Let’s simplify the sentence for the sake of explanation:

> They spent a week ***engaged/engaging*** in interfaith dialogue.

**WHY “ENGAGED” IS CORRECT?**

> They spent a week **engaged** in interfaith dialogue.

SEMANTIC:

They spent a week and during the week they were engaged in interfaith dialogue.

GRAMMAR:

That ***“engaged”*** in the quoted sentence is a Participial Adjective, formed from the Past Participle form of verb.  And ***”engaged in interfaith dialogue”*** is an Adjective Phrase (AdjP).

Functionally that AdjP can be interpreted in two ways:

i) It can be an optional Depicitive Predicative Complement (PC) 
ii) It can be a Predicative Adjunct

[Reference: Cambridge Grammar of english Language – Page No. 529 and 261]

Consider the following sentences -

> 1. He died **young**.
> 2. He was buried **alive**.
> 3. He was burnt **alive**.

In each of the sentences above, **young** and **alive** are adjectives and they are optional. They can be regarded as either a Predicative Adjunct or a Depictive Predicative Complement.

> All adjectives that can function as predicative adjunct can also unction as predicative complement.

In our sentence -

> They spent a week **engaged in interfaith dialogue**.

The AdjP - **engaged in interfaith dialogue** - can be considered as a second complement of the predicator - **spend**, in which case it is an optional Depictive Predicative Complement related to the predicand - **they**. That adjP can also be considered as a Predicative Adjunct.

**WHY “ENGAGING” IS CORRECT?**

> They spent a week **engaging** in interfaith dialogue.

SEMANTIC:

They spent a week and during the week they were engaged in interfaith dialogue.

GRAMMAR:

Here ***engaging in interfaith dialogue*** is a Gerund-Participle clause, that functions as a manner adjunct in the quoted sentence.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems you can't extrapolate this to any general case.  It still seems to vary from verb to verb.  For example, *They spend a week **stranded** in the mountains* (but not **stranding**).  Or *They spent a week **skiing** in the mountains* (but not **skied**).  In other cases the form used changes the meaning, *They spent an hour **parked/parking** by the side of the road.*

Comment: @Andrew hmmm I never had thought about it. I am unable to differentiate the meaning difference in your last sentence, can you please tell me. And about "stranded", I don't know why, but "stranding" also seems right to me. And no idea about"skiing" :-) but can't rely much on my intuition. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between "They were engaged" in something and "They were engaging" in something.  The first suggests a *condition* while the second suggests an *action*.  In the context of your question, the meaning is much the same, but with *parked/parking* it's very different.  To be *parked* means to have the car fully stopped, while to be *parking* means you're trying to find a place (or a way) to park.  So with the first they were stopped in the car for an hour, and the second, they were looking for parking for an hour.

Comment: I should probably write all this up as a separate answer :)